# GWT: multiple column sorting

Tags: gwt

I am trying to do multiple columns sorting in my application .

Like i have firstname , last name columns

Right now , when i click on firstname header , it sorts as per firstname , when i click on lastname column it sorts as per lastname column..

what i need is when i click on firstname header it should sort on the basis of firstname and then if i click on lastname(with shift or any other option) header it should sort on the basis of both firstname and lastname , firstname as primary column and last name as sub sorting column

here is what i have now

```java
private void sortTableUsers(List<UserDTO> userList){

    ListDataProvider<UserDTO> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<UserDTO>();
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(usersTable);

    List<UserDTO> list = dataProvider.getList();

    for (UserDTO UserDTO : userList) {
    list.add(UserDTO);
    }
    final ListHandler<UserDTO> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<UserDTO>(list);

        columnSortHandler.setComparator(firstNameColumn,new Comparator<UserDTO>() {

        public int compare(UserDTO o1,UserDTO o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
        }

        // Compare the firstname columns.
        if (o1 != null) {

        return (o2 != null) ? o1.getUser().getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getUser().getFirstName()) : 1;
        }
        return -1;
        }
        });


    columnSortHandler.setComparator(lastNameColumn,new Comparator<UserDTO>() {

        public int compare(UserDTO o1,UserDTO o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
        }

        // Compare the lastname columns.
        if (o1 != null) {

        return (o2 != null) ? o1.getUser().getLastName().compareTo(o2.getUser().getLastName()) : 1;
        }
        return -1;
        }
        });


        usersTable.getColumnSortList().push(firstNameColumn);
        usersTable.getColumnSortList().push(middleNameColumn);
}
```

Comment: The way this is usually done is, that when you click on firstname, and then on lastname (doesn't need any shift key), then lastname becomes the primary (!) sorting criteria, and firstname the secondary (which is quite intuitive when you try it). This can generally be achieved with [stable sort algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts).

Comment: Is the question about the header that should catch the shift key pressed or about the sorting algorithm ?

Comment: @ChrisLercher: and if I'm not mistaken, that's exactly what the above code does (`ListHandler` updates the list in-place, rather than starting back from the "unsorted" list, and uses `Collections.sort()` which guarantees a stable sort).

Comment: this is about  sorting .. (NOT shift key , thats not important)..If i click on the second column , the first coluumn should remain sorted , that what is not happening

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need a different comparator for each column, the second comparator is the one that you need to change.
First it must sort for FirstName,and if the firstnames are equal, then go on and compare the last names too.
I'm not using your DTO, and i don't check for nulls, but it's the same thing, you get the idea

```
ArrayList<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();
ListHandler<Map> _sortHandler = new ListHandler<Map>(list);

Column columnDefinitionFirstName = null; // create your column first name
columnDefinitionFirstName.setSortable(true);

//
_sortHandler.setComparator(columnDefinitionFirstName, new Comparator<Map>()
{
    public int compare(Map o1, Map o2)
    {
        int res = 0;

        String object1 = (String) o1.get("FIRST_NAME");
        String object2 = (String) o2.get("FIRST_NAME");

        res = object1.compareTo(object2);

        return res;
    }
});



Column columnDefinitionLastName = null; // create your column last name
columnDefinitionLastName.setSortable(true);



_sortHandler.setComparator(columnDefinitionLastName, new Comparator<Map>()
{
    public int compare(Map o1, Map o2)
    {
        int res = 0;

        String object1 = (String) o1.get("FIRST_NAME");
        String object2 = (String) o2.get("FIRST_NAME");

        res = object1.compareTo(object2);

        if(res == 0)
        {
             String object11 = (String) o1.get("LAST_NAME");
             String object22 = (String) o2.get("LAST_NAME");

             res = object11.compareTo(object22);
        }

        return res;
    }
});
```